# Yahoo finance inaccurate stock data

Tags: yahoo

Why is Yahoo Finance historical stock price data inaccurate? See examples:
`AAPL` - actual closing prices in 2012 when AAPL previously closed > $100/share adjusted for 7:1 split;
chart & data do not agree, esp when picking different time periods, e.g. "Max" vs "5 year" vs 'Custom". Historical data is also incorrect. These closing prices are wrong:

```
Sep 21, 2012 95.12 
Sep 20, 2012  94.93 
Sep 19, 2012 95.39
```

**NASDAQ**

Similar inaccuracies, look at charts & historical data for peak close in March, 2000 > \$5000 when Yahoo data reflects correct closing prices but Yahoo charts never get above $3100.

Apparently discrepancies are rampant..

Answer (score 3):

I think this question has been answered here before (regarding yahoo finance & historical data).  Most free providers of historical data do not take the time to go back & $fix$ the data discrepancies such as the one you ran into. I believe they just collect/update data as it comes I.e. Stock splits, dividend payments. However, the Adjusted Close column should reflect the most "accurate" historical price such as the High that $AAPL$ had before the split ~ $700/share is now ~$100/share after the 7:1 split.

Comment: If this has been answered before, please can you post a link for where you recommend I can find out more?